# Is conjunction reduction possible within an if's compound apodosis?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, conditionals, modal-verbs, subordinate-clauses, conjunction-reduction

I have the following sentence:

> If the researcher knew the mechanism, any feature of the population **would be** known, any (causal) relationships in the population **would be** completely traceable, and any realization of that population **would be** completely predictable.

In this case, it is extremly unlikely the researcher will ever know "the mechanism", so we use *if* + past tense in the conditional's protasis followed by modal *would* + infinitive in its resulting apodosis.

My question: Do I **have to** fully repeat *would be* in every conjoined clause, or can I also simplify by writing:

> If the researcher knew the mechanism, any feature of the population **would be** known, any (causal) relationships in the population **be** completely traceable, and any realization of that population **be** completely predictable.

I can't really say why, but somehow this second version sounds right to me. However, being a non-native speaker, I'd rather ask for guidance here.

Comment: As usual, you can "delete" the ***completely predictable*** second and third instances of ***would be*** in your text. But whereas I'd say it's probably "syntactically valid" to only delete the word ***would***, I think the end result isn't very fluent. It's really just a stylistic choice, but I suggest you ***delete both words or neither.***

Comment: There is always a trade-off when making (grammatically acceptable) deletions. Your suggested version sounds at best awkward, FF's more fluent. I think the sectioning off by commas-and -_any'_s  ... + ... _population_'s aid parsing sufficiently, so I'd say conciseness triumphs over belt-and-braces clarity _in this particular case_.